# Connecting to mongos router from Visual Studio 2010 application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, connection-string, mongodb, mongo-shell

I am somewhat new to MongoDB and this might be a silly thing to ask but I'm trying to set up a sharded cluster. I have two mongods running on two different machines, say A and B, on ports 10000 and 20000 respectively.

On machine A itself, I have configured the mongos as well (on port 27019) and added the above two shards on it..My chunks collection is also sharded with proper key. I know how to access the database from mongos shell..But I have an ASP.NET application that I want to connect to mongos..

Before sharding, when I was having just one database on default port on one machine, I was using this connection string in the application:

```
string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
```

Now I want to connect to "mongos"..something like:

```
string connectionString = "mongos://localhost:27019";
```

I tried : `"mongodb://localhost:27019"`; But it didn't work which is actually fine because I 'know' there's no mongod there!

How should I do this? Or am I missing a core concept here?

Thanks in advance :)

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in connecting to mongodb or mongos.  It will be the same connection string as the driver doesn't care whether it is connecting to mongod or mongos.  AS you mentioned you tried it, ensure that you have the host and ports correctly identified.

Comment: Thanks! I tried again,somewhat differently..and it worked:) Like you pointed out, there was some problem with the connection before. But I don't understand one thing: Following the example on http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/A+Sample+Configuration+Session, I set up configsvr @ 27019 and so was specifying configdb also at 27019 and it reported "same port can't be reused"..So I tried this: mongos --port 30000 --configdb <machine-dns>:27019 and changed the connection string to mongodb://localhost:30000. It worked smoothly after that :)